# Error:(31, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I m trying to use Gabriele Mariotti card library , From github using https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib.

Currently I'm using Android Studio, so I have added the dependencies to my build gradle file as mentioned in the documentation.

This is what my gradle file looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vt"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':addslidepanel30')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v7-palette.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3-with-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')

    //Core
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-core:2.0.1'

    //Optional for built-in cards
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-cards:2.0.1'

    //Optional for RecyclerView
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-recyclerview:2.0.1'

    //Optional for staggered grid view
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-extra-staggeredgrid:2.0.1'

    //Optional for drag and drop
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-extra-dragdrop:2.0.1'

    //Optional for twoway  (coming soon)
    //compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-extra-twoway:2.0.1'
}
```

**But I keep getting this message error**

```
Error:(31, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library C:\Users\SAM-PC\AndroidStudioProjects\vt1.3.0.0 newDB\vt1300newDB\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards\library\1.9.1\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(31, 5) Execution failed for task ':vt1300newDB:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library C:\Users\SAM-PC\AndroidStudioProjects\vt1.3.0.0 newDB\vt1300newDB\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards\library\1.9.1\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="it.gmariotti.cardslib.library" to force usage
```

I have tried to change the version of the card lib to the stable, But I'm keep getting the same error

```
dependencies {
    //Core card library
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library:1.9.1'

    //Extra card library, it is required only if you want to use integrations with other libraries
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:library-extra:1.9.1'
}
```

PS : I'm new to Android Studio , My project works just fine in Eclipse , but I m trying to Migrate to Android Studio since it s recommended by google .so I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="14"
          tools:overrideLibrary="it.gmariotti.cardslib.library"/>
```

More info can be found [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:overrideLibrary-marker).

Comment: Thank you , I have changed the minSdk to 9 , and it s working

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="14"
      tools:overrideLibrary="it.gmariotti.cardslib.library"/>
```

You need to change `minSdkVersion` of your project to 14 or change that of `it.gmariotti.cardslib.library`  to 9. Because the `minSdkVersion` of the imported  library is 14.